# Problem with installing Rtools: cannot locate the file in PATH

Tags: r, rtools

I'm trying to download the package "Seurat" in R, the package is installed and it's now in my list of packages.

```
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (patchwork)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\parnian\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpAVgSd8\downloaded_packages’
```

But when I try to call it (library(Seurat)) I get the following error:

```
> library(Seurat)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Seurat’:
 object ‘wrap_plots’ is not exported by 'namespace:patchwork'
```

I read the similar questions and manually installed "patchwork":

```
 > install.packages("patchwork")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/parnian/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

R also tells me to install Rtools whhich I have, but when I follow these commands:

```
> writeLines('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\\usr\\bin;${PATH}"', con = "~/.Renviron")
```

but when I want to verify that `make` can be found (`Sys.which("make")`), I get this:

```
> Sys.which("make")
make 
  ""
```

Also the downloaded packages of Seurat are saved in a location that doesn't even exist in my computer! How is that possible?
How can I fix this? Is there something wrong with the address I write for the path?
Thank you

Comment: Have you already tried restarting your machine?

Comment: Should I restart the machine? The instructions on rstudio website say that I must restart the R machine which I do. The problem is that the website says to create .Renviron in a location that doesn't exist. The location of rtools files in my computer is in C://rtools40/home and then there is no more folders in home. But the website tells me to create the .Renviron in C://RTOOLS40/HOME... and we know R is case sensitive. Should I change the location of .Renviron file? I can't put RTools in my PATH.

Comment: I meant following [this](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) instructions, what you probably did _and_ restarting your machine before you do anything else.

Comment: Yes I followed the instructions of that page and I think the location int instructs me to create the .Renviron file is wrong.

Comment: Which windows version are you running?

Comment: Windows 10 on ASUS laptop, but I dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213061/discussion-between-jay-sf-and-parnian).